# Data Loading Sequence for Account ParentId

Tags: metadata-api, talend

I would like to know the proper data loading sequence.  I know to start with Accounts then Contacts and so forth.  I used an External_Id__c field for the id pulled from prod.  So how do I map the ParentId to the newly created Id's based on the external Id.  I'm using Talend which is connected to Salesforce and MS SQL Server.  It seems that what I want to accomplish goes with the following logic:

```
SELECT External_Id__c FROM Account
Search ParentId column
WHERE (ParentId = External_Id__c) {
    ParentId = Id FROM Row WHERE External_Id__c matched
}
```

I know the above is crude, but I wanted to attempt to express what i'm trying to accomplish. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

step1. insert accounts with external Id
step2. insert contact records
step3. upsert contact records with proper parent Account mapping using "external Id associated with the parent account".